# Parse retrieve PFObject with Pointer

Tags: swift, pointers, parse-platform, pfquery

I have two classes Place and BeenHere. BeenHere has pointers called "toPlace" and "fromUser"with target to Class Place and User accordingly. Place, in its turn, has title and image (PFFile) that I want to retrieve and show in ViewController. In the code below I have reached that pointer with objectId, but don't know how I can now retrieve title and image related to specific place this pointer leads to. Appreciate your help and suggestions.

```
class UserBeenHereViewController: UIViewController {       
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

    if user != nil {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "BeenHere")
            query.includeKey("toPlace")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                print(object["toPlace"].objectId)

            }
        }
            else {
                print("There is error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the "toPlace" into a PFObject and then access it. So in your case it should look something like:

```
var toPlace = comment["toPlace"] as? PFObject
print (toPlace["title"])
```